# How to avoid inline javascript with generated content and CSS inline performance comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

So I read that inline javascript is bad (not cacheable), so I try to put all my script in separate file, but how do you avoid inline javascript if it is generated based on content, for example in ASP.NET-MVC.

```
$('#id').showPopUp({
    text: @Model.Message //Dynamic value from controller
})
```

I also have question about inline CSS, I understand that it is best to use class if you need more than 1 style, but what if I only need one style, for example :

```
.width100 {width: 100%;} //CSS stylesheet
<table class="width100"></table>
```

VS

```
<table style="width: 100%;"></table>
```

which one is better in performance?

Sorry for bad english.
Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

And how do I avoid inline for dynamic generated js? For example :

```
@{ if (flag = true) }
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#id').getIn();
</script>

@{ else }
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#id').getOut();
</script>
```

Comment: Inline CSS should be avoided if possible - not because of performance reasons, but due to the very high specificity of it, meaning display rules set by inline CSS cannot be overwritten by other regular CSS rules, which makes developing and maintaining this code a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [html-5  custom data attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) for this:

```
<div id="SomeDiv" data-message="@Model.Message">
</div>
```

and in js file:

```
$('#SomeDiv').showPopUp({
    text: $("#SomeDiv").data("message")
})
```

Comment: Works! Now I have another question. What about dynamic rendered javascript? Please read my edited message.

Comment: that you cannot add in separate js file because razor is server side so it is only accessible in view